# What is the Eclipse equivalent of IntelliJ Ctrl + N

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA we can navigate to a class using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> shortcut and typing its name.
What is the Eclipse equivalent of this?

Comment: You can find a comprehensive collection of shortcuts from both worlds [in this article](https://darekkay.com/2014/02/27/intellij-idea-shortcuts-for-eclipse-users/) which, is suggested, was the staring point for this [github project which allows searching/filering](http://gaerfield.github.io/ide-shortcuts/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Open Type](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-open-type.htm) (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>**) to open a Java type
- [Open Resource](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-open-resource.htm) (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**) to open a file by its name

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is Eclipse equivalent to IntelliJ IDEA's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to find a type or class.