# Eclipse: How to find enum literals?

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

#### Background

I just recently had to transition from Idea to Eclipse.

#### What I am looking for

I am looking for an enum somewhere in my workspace or the dependencies. It should have literals like "EMPTY" or "TOO_LARGE".

#### Question

In Idea, I could just use the usual class search CTRL+N for this and type the literal name. But in Eclipse, using the Type or Resource searches ignore Enum literals. How can I reconfigure Eclipse, or how can I perform a search for literals?

#### Duplicate edit

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212558/what-is-the-eclipse-equivalent-of-intellij-ctrl-n) about the equivalent of Idea's CTRL+N in Eclipse which seems the same, but in fact is not. My question is about the aspect of the CTRL+N search in Idea where you could even find enum literals as if they were own types. I miss this feature a lot, because it's so neccessary for reusing code.

#### Summary of the answer

As Andreas pointed out, there is a pretty good way to find enum literals in Eclipse: Utilize Java Search and filter for field declarations.

Comment: Without checking (there's very likely a better solution), you could just search for text `EMPTY` in `*.java` (`Ctrl-H`, then navigate to the text search tab). Will update if I have something better.

Comment: @Mena: That's a flawed solution because there are so many duplicates and even with Java search I could not yield better results.

Comment: @GeorgMuehlenberg yeah it's not ideal but my IDE is so busy right now I can't look for better solutions...try the answer(s) below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select project or root node of source code to search in the "Package Explorer" pane on the left, then use pull-down menu `Search` > `Java`, select "Search for `Field`" and "Limit to `Declarations`".

Comment: That's very close to what I wanted to achieve, thank you! 
Although there is an easier way to get to this menu. You can hit CTRL+H and configure which search dialogues to display there with the Customize button.